# How to return top x distinct sum of sales?

Tags: sql, distinct

I am super stuck with solving a problem in getting what I want in SQL. I have been able to achieve the same in excel but am looking at solving this as a learning step into getting a better understanding in SQL. Imagine both of the following excel tables are 1:1 in a SQL Server datatabase as well:

**Product**

[image: Product]

**Sales - this has 8000 rows**

[image: Sales]

And the result I want to see is the following:

[image: Result]

So far, I have been able to get the counts of each category and productname with the following SQL script:

```
SELECT
dp.ProductCategoryName,
dp.ProductName,
sum(fs.SalesAmount) as 'TotalSalesAmount'
FROM 
dbo.Product dp
JOIN dbo.Sales fs ON 
fs.ProductID = dp.ProductID
GROUP BY 
dp.ProductCategoryName, dp.ProductName, fs.SalesAmount
ORDER BY 
sum(fs.SalesAmount)
```

But this is not even close to the result I want. I want to calculate total sales amount for each products under each category, then return only top 2 highest selling products in each category.  I'm not sure how to get the distinct product name and category as well while calculating the sums. Can someone please help me through this as this is all very confusing! I am trying to understand the steps I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this to achieve top max 2 lines for  a category:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTop2 (@category AS int) 
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(category AS int,
    prodId AS int,
    salesSum AS int) 
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @result
SELECT top 2 p.category ,
           s.prodId ,
           sum(sales) AS saleasSum
FROM tblsales AS s
INNER JOIN tblProd AS p ON p.id = s.prodId 
WHERE p.category  = @category 
GROUP BY p.category ,
         s.prodId 
ORDER BY saleasSum DESC 
RETURN 
END;
```

Comment: would there be any way to do it without creating a function?

Comment: Maybe by using a loop with cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
select * into Product from (
values(1,'Bike','Auto'),
(2,'Car','Auto'),
(3,'Truck','Auto'),
(4,'Wheat','Grain'),
(5,'Rice','Grain'),
(6,'Barley','Grain'),
(7,'Eggplant','Vegetable'),
(8,'Okra','Vegetable'),
(9,'Cabage','Vegetable')) as t(Productid, ProductName,ProductCategoryName)

select * into Sales from (
values ('2021-06-06',1,10000),
('2021-06-06',2,20000),
('2021-06-06',3,100000),
('2021-06-06',4,2000),
('2021-06-06',5,2500),
('2021-06-06',6,3000),
('2021-06-06',7,100),
('2021-06-06',8,200),
('2021-06-06',9,300),
('2021-06-05',1,1000),
('2021-06-05',2,2000),
('2021-06-05',3,10000),
('2021-06-05',4,200),
('2021-06-05',5,250),
('2021-06-05',6,300),
('2021-06-05',7,10),
('2021-06-05',8,20),
('2021-06-05',9,30)
) as t([Date], Productid,SalesAmount)

Select productCategoryName, Productname, SalesAmount
from(
Select
p.productCategoryName, p.Productname, sum(s.SalesAmount) SalesAmount,
row_number() over (partition by p.productCategoryName order by sum(s.SalesAmount) desc) rnum
From Sales s
join Product p on s.productid = p.productid
group by p.productCategoryName, p.Productname
) a where rnum in (1,2)
order by productCategoryName, SalesAmount desc
```